# JSONObject parsed on android 4.0, but not on earlier versions

Tags: android, json

I have this code which fetches a json string from a website:

```
post.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
result = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);
```

This is an example of the json in result:

```
{"status":"0","user_id":"123","name":"test","session_code":"6f33d4ee610651530f04b1f700ebc36d"}
```

which validates on jsonlint.com. I try to parse it using

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(result);
```

On android 4, the code works fine, but on earlier versions, it gives

```
org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

When I hard coded the json string instead of getting it online, it worked on earlier versions. When I logged the http request output I found that it's identical in every thing except for the session code which changes with every successful request but both session codes had the same length and format.

Any one knows what is the reason for this and how to fix it?

---

UPDATE:

```
if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()){
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        String postURL = "http://www.xxxxxx.com/api/login.php";
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
        List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", password));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams, HTTP.UTF_8);
        post.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
        HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
        result = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}

if (result != null) {
    try {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(result);

        switch (jo.getInt("status")) {
            case 0 : {
                userName = jo.getString("name");
                userID = jo.getInt("user_id");
                authCode = jo.getString("session_code");

                return 0;
            }

            default:
                return jo.getInt("status");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use JSON on android from Android 2.3.3 version itself.. Share yours Code for Discussion

Comment: Try JSONArray instead of JSONObject.

Comment: try this result = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

Comment: there has to be a difference in the string. can you post the complete request + parse code ?

Answer (score 0):

try this `result = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);`

Comment: It produced this: ï»¿{"status":"0","user_id":"123","name":"test","session_code":"8d76df4d5e3663fe839b4f3c57ede2e9"} I also need the utf-8 encoding because I receive arabic content which needs to be parsed as utf-8.

Comment: does you need any special characters in response, if not then ask server guy to replace those special characters this will solve your problem. other wise you need to parsed as UTF-8 & before giving that input to json you need to replace those special characters but make sure you are getting same special characters in response.

Comment: Arabic letters are in UTF, I have to use UTF-8 encoding. What I want to understand is why does it work perfectly on ice cream sandwich but not earlier versions although the JSONObject library is API level 1?!!!

Comment: ï»¿  - can you please tell what is this? It seems like there are some characters in front of your content..

Comment: These characters appear when I use EntityUtils.toString(resEntity) instead of EntityUtils.toString(resEntity, HTTP.UTF_8).

Comment: The ï»¿ makes me wonder if your php script has a correct encoding. Could be that it outputs polluted characters that only Android past a certain version handles correctly.

Comment: The "result" json string is the output of [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) supplied with the output array of a mySQL query on a UTF-8 encoded table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement UTF-8 encoding also on the server side (PHP, Node, etc.) to get the web service (JSON parsing) working correctly on your older Android (<4.0) devices. Try this one! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem with version.

You may have to check your all types of `response` that you are returning.

May you are returning `String` if error occurred.

If you converting `result` as `JSONObject` every time then you must have to return `JSONObject` as a `String`